# How much space is required in my SML code?

Tags: sml, space-complexity

I have SML code like below.

```
fun fact(n) =
    let fun f(n,g) = if n=0 then g(1)
                     else f(n-1, fn x=>g(x)*n)
in f(n, fn x=> x) end;
```

I want to know how much space is required in my code for computing fact(n).
Is it right it requires O(n)? I don't know exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the function you wrote creates *n* closures before evaluating them at the end.

Here is a more space-efficient version:

```
fun fact n =
    let fun fact' 0 result = result
          | fact' n result = fact' (n-1) (n*result)
    in fact' n 1 end
```

It resolves `n*result` before making a recursive call, rather than delaying it, making it tail-recursive.